# loop in python !

Tags: python

can anyone help me with loop i want loop that code

```
login_form_data = urllib.urlencode(login_form_seq)
 opener = urllib2.build_opener()
 site = opener.open(B, login_form_data).read()
```

the code allow me to login to site but site have problem and the problem is: you can't login from first time

that mean I have to press submit then when page reload press submit again... so i think loop will do that but How!?

Comment: Please choose a more meaningful title for your question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to handle cookies. Look at [the cookielib module](http://docs.python.org/library/cookielib.html).

Answer (score 1):

If it *is* a cookie handling problem, use the "[HTTPCookieProcessor](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html?highlight=urllib2#urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor)" in urllib2.
By applying it to your opener.

```
cookieHandler = urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor() # Needed for cookie handling

# Apply the handler to an opener
opener = urllib2.build_opener(cookieHandler)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not accepting and saving the cookie(s) required by the page you are trying to access. This is not surprising given that `urllib2` does not automatically do this for you. As others have said you'll have to explicitly write code to accept cookies. Something like this:

```
import urllib2, cookielib
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

login_form_data = urllib.urlencode(login_form_seq)
site = opener.open(B, login_form_data).read()
```

This would be a good time to read up about [`cookielib`](http://docs.python.org/library/cookielib.html) and [HTTP state management](http://docs.python.org/library/cookie.html) in Python.

Comment: well sir it's not depend on cookies so just tell me how to make it submit twice time !